# How to hide / show everything inside of a div using jquery and an HTML button?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, togglebutton

How do I use an HTML button to hide a div and all of its contents within it using jquery.

**(Be aware of the divs contents and the way they are set up are completely necessary)**

The button:

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Toggle" />
```

The div:

```
<div class="holder">
    <iframe class="frame"
            src="http://www.google.com/custom"
            data-url="http://www.google.com/custom?q="
            width="250"
            height="600" 
            onmouseover="width = 400" 
            onmouseout="width = 250">
    </iframe>
    <div class="sampleDiv">
        <a class="invisibleDiv" 
           id="http://www.google.com/custom?q=" 
           href="http://www.google.com/custom?q=" 
           target="Goog"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
 function virtualSubmit(form) {
        var text = form.searchtext.value;
        var targets = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'), items = targets.length;
        var targets2 = document.getElementsByClassName('invisibleDiv'), items2 =      targets2.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        var target = targets[i], url = target.getAttribute('data-url');
        }

 for (var i = 0; i < items2; i++) {
        var target = targets2[i], url = target.getAttribute('href');
         target.href = target.id + text;

  }
 return false;

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#button").click(function () {
    var holder= this.value;
      $(".holder").slideToggle().siblings().hide("slow");
    });

 });
```

A fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/2xLNd/

Comment: The investigation? - you even call the button the name of the jquery function you want https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I've updated this with the JS so it might be better to understand the issue.

Comment: @Ibounes post a fiddle narrowing down your issue.

Comment: This is a great example of where the [`summary` and `details`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) elements in HTML5 would be in order, rather than 20 lines of code. I recommend looking into using it and a [polyfil fallback](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-details-jquery) for [browsers that don't support it yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=details).

Comment: @Ibounes you are missing a `}` after `return false`.

Comment: Thanks you @Shouvik didnt seem to make much of a difference though...

Comment: @Ibounes [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/xkQh6/2/)

Comment: if I fire $(".holder").toggle(); in the console. Its working fine.

Comment: @SSS yeah that worked for me as well but when I link it with the button it does not...

Comment: check the answer I have posted. Its working on my side. Have also added the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Using JQuery you can simply do this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#button").click(function()
            {
                  $(".holder").hide();
            });

        });</script>
```

if you want to hide and show the div then you can use

```
<script> $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#button").click(function()
        {
              $(".holder").toggle();
        });

    });</script>
```

Comment: have you added <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script> in head

Comment: Yeah I have. thats not the issue

Comment: I have checked your same code, it is perfectly working.

Comment: @Ibounes [Check your brackets!](http://jsfiddle.net/2xLNd/7/) and also you did not reference the jquery library.

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/2xLNd/4/

You have document ready in a function. Keep it out of the scope of the function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function () {
    $(".holder").toggle();
  });
});
```

Your function should end before document.ready is called.

Comment: Yeah... It would querry a search in the iframe

Comment: I checked your old code(fiddle) its not working there either.
Check your old fiddle. Might be because we are checking it on fiddle

Comment: Your return to the form is not triggering the function

Comment: The issues is in the function for showing the result and not in the issue for toggle and fade. I guess your div hide and show issues is resolved in this. Please mark it as right answer if you feel and open a new discussion for the iframe issue. With proper question tags

Answer (score 1):

You can you the following code in you jQuery.

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    $(".holder").toggle();
});
```

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/yv3Xf/) for example

Update: Looking at your code you can try this.

```
$("#button").click(function () {
var holder= this.value;
  $(".holder").toggle("slideUp");
});

});
```

Just remove siblings(). And your function in not closed properly. check the link above.

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9NN8Q/)

Comment: @lbounes: add jquery library in your fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could simple do `$(".holder").hide()` to make the div invisible and `$(".holder").show()` to make the div visible again.

Comment: I've tried this and it did not work... I think its because of the div's contents.

Comment: What did you try and what was the expected and actual result and console messages?

Comment: Nothing happened and It was expected to hide the Iframe inside of the div

Comment: Is there any error in the logs? Have you included jQuery in your html?

Answer (score 0):

In order to show/ hide a particlar DIV , you need to make use of jquery in built methods toggle()

if you want initially Holder div to be display none , then

```
<div class="holder" style="display:none;">
    <iframe class="frame"
            src="http://www.google.com/custom"
            data-url="http://www.google.com/custom?q="
            width="250"
            height="600" 
            onmouseover="width = 400" 
            onmouseout="width = 250">
    </iframe>
    <div class="sampleDiv">
        <a class="invisibleDiv" 
           id="http://www.google.com/custom?q=" 
           href="http://www.google.com/custom?q=" 
           target="Goog"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like in your case , if you want to hide/show  a div then you will simply use

```
$('#button').click(function() {

    $(".holder").toggle();      

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks try this one

```
<div class="holder">
    <iframe class="frame"
            src="http://www.google.com/custom"
            data-url="http://www.google.com/custom?q="
            width="250"
            height="600" 
            onmouseover="width = 400" 
            onmouseout="width = 250">
    </iframe>
    <div class="sampleDiv">
        <a class="invisibleDiv" 
           id="http://www.google.com/custom?q=" 
           href="http://www.google.com/custom?q=" 
           target="Goog"></a>
    </div>
</div>

<input id="button" type="button" value="Toggle" />

<script>
 function virtualSubmit(form) {
        var text = form.searchtext.value;
        var targets = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'), items = targets.length;
        var targets2 = document.getElementsByClassName('invisibleDiv'), items2 =      targets2.length;

 for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        var target = targets[i], url = target.getAttribute('data-url');
        }

 for (var i = 0; i < items2; i++) {
        var target = targets2[i], url = target.getAttribute('href');
         target.href = target.id + text;

  }
 return false;
}
$("#button").click(function () {
    $(".holder").toggle(); 

    });



</script>
```

one closing currly braces was missing below return false.

Answer (score 0):

hi dear friends this link usefull for you...[demo_Click_hear](http://jsfiddle.net/2xLNd/5/)

hi dear please add jquery-1.8.3 add library .........

```
function virtualSubmit(form) {
            var text = form.searchtext.value;
            var targets = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'), items = targets.length;
            var targets2 = document.getElementsByClassName('invisibleDiv'), items2 = targets2.length;

     for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            var target = targets[i], url = target.getAttribute('data-url');
            }

     for (var i = 0; i < items2; i++) {
            var target = targets2[i], url = target.getAttribute('href');
             target.href = target.id + text;

}
return false;
 }
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button").click(function () {
        $("div.holder").toggle();
        });
 });
```